# How to iterate and print Matrix over jtextfield?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print sequences of numbers of a matrix into a jtextfield.
My for loops work fine when working on the console but won't do on the text field.

```
private void btnperformAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                           
        int [][] boardOne = defineBoard(); //initializes matrix   
        fillBoard(boardOne); //adds integers values to the matrix
        int i,j;

        for(i = 0; i < boardOne.length; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < boardOne[i].length; j++){
                txtField.setText("" + boardOne[i][j]); 
         }
        }
```

These are the would be values printed on the console that I need on the jtextfield

```
    8   19  39  63  66  
    6   21  32  61  72  
    4   26  -1  64  74  
    5   20  33  55  76  
    14  16  35  51  80
```

And the text field will only output the very last number, `80` in this case. Why is this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `txtField.setText("" + boardOne[i][j]);` - this line overwrites the text every time it is called. You probably want to construct a String in the loop first and then set it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate previous textfield value. currently you are setting value at current position loop is referring. change your code to something like below

```
txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + boardOne[i][j]);
```

Comment: Hi, I did it this way and it worked but the output is a single long string and I can't use it this way, is there any way in which the sequences can be arranged on 5 columns of 5 values?

Comment: add newline char when your inner loop completes `txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "\n"); ` put this line after inner loop

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `setText` method replaces any existing text. So you only get the last element in your matrix, which is `80`.

You can use a `StringBuilder` to build the entire string in the loop, and then set the string to the JTextField.